# How to load content view inside a tableview cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, swift-playground

I have created a table view as

```
 var tblView : UITableView = UITableView()
        tblView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 168, 320-50 , 450)
        tblView.separatorColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        tblView.scrollEnabled = false
        tblView.rowHeight = 39
        self.addSubview(tblView)
        tblView.delegate = self
        tblView.dataSource = self
        tblView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "myCell")
```

Now i am trying to add custom view to the tableviewcell as

```
 //MARK:  table view data source methods
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     var cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell") as UITableViewCell
     var cellImgView:UIImageView = UIImageView()
     cellImgView.frame = CGRectMake(cell.contentView.frame.origin.x+10, cell.contentView.frame.size.height, 20, 20)
     let cellImage = UIImage(named: self.cellImgs[indexPath.row])
     cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.000, green: 0.400, blue: 0.404, alpha: 1.00)
     cellImgView = UIImageView(image: cellImage)
     cell.contentView.addSubview(cellImgView)
     return cell
}
```

Only first image is at correct position and other are overlapped.Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

cellForRowAtIndexPath will called each time when cell in user's sight.
But you need add UIImageView only once. So, you need to check, is there is the first call.

Also, it is good practice to use custom UITableViewCell

Comment: that  doesnot fix it.As you said, i tried to check using Switch Case for indexpath.row and for case 0 i initialized the imageview.

Comment: No, I didn't mean this.

Create UITableViewCell subclass. Add into it UIImageView. In cellForRow allocate this UIImageView only if it is not created already.

Answer (score 0):

Tableview is reusing created cells, so your approach is not the best. What you are doing now is creating UIImageView everytime a cell is being used and if its a cells that is going to be reused you will create new UIImageView on top of your previous one.

I would suggest to do all this in interface builder. If you dont want to, at least subclass UITableViewCell and create image view in init method of your cell, that will take care of overlapping UIImageviews over each other, but still consider using interface builder, its the easiest way to build tableviews.

#### EDIT

Here's some tutorial on tableviews in interface builder, this should help you get started: http://shrikar.com/blog/2015/01/17/uitableview-and-uitableviewcell-customization-in-swift/

Good luck!

Comment: inorder to reuse created cells, i have to scroll the tableview and only for new cells it will dequeue the first one ?

Comment: @anishparajuli basically, it will reuse cells when you scroll, thats where your problem is with creating new imageview over one which is there already(if you indeed scroll in your tableview), either way u'll need to subclass UITableViewCell()

Comment: but i am trying to give user to go to next view controller after clicking on a row. And i dont need too many rows so  i have disabled scrolling property